# How to view signing algorithm of a loadable kernel module?

Tags: system-installation, kernel

I am trying to read the signing algorithm(like SHA512) of a kernel module. I am using Ubuntu machine with Kernel (3.13.0-68-generic).

I tried using modinfo command, but it doesn't tell me the signature algorithm.

```
$sudo /sbin/modinfo netlinkKernel.ko 
filename:       netlinkKernel.ko
license:        GPL
srcversion:     9FC7512864C356D4A8AD301
depends:        
vermagic:       3.13.0-68-generic SMP mod_unload modversions
```

In RedHatLinux, modinfo apparently shows many more fields including signature algorithm. But the same command is not showing these details in my Ubuntu machine.

I need to know which algorithm was used to sign the module. Can someone please let me know the command?